# Error C2075 при инициализации массива

Tags: c++, лямбда-выражение

```
int info[4];
std::thread threads[4];
for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    threads[i] = std::thread([info](){
    });
}
```

> ```
> Error C2075 <lambda_8055d813359f7c91517489d9e5366436>::info": 
> для инициализации массива требуется список инициализаторов, заключенный в фигурные скобки
> ```

Comment: Please write russian language . this form intended for ruasian.

Comment: переменная `json *info[4];` не инициализирована

Comment: Я пробовал. Не помогает.

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите код к виду [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь захватить `info` по значению, а так нельзя - это массив.
Захватывайте по ссылке - `&info`.

Comment: А как нужно сделать?

Comment: Там скорее вообще `info[i]` надо захватывать, а то как-то странно.

Comment: Спасибо, ошибка исчезла.

Comment: Любопытно, что это характерно только для msvc.

Answer (score 0):

Ваша проблема, о которой уже сказал @Abyx в своём ответе, актуальна только для *MS Visual C++*. По стандарту захват массива по значению в лямбду приводит к копированию значений в [объект замыкания](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15423723/3240681):

> When the lambda-expression is evaluated, the entities that are captured by copy are used to direct-initialize each corresponding non-static data member of the resulting closure object. (For array members, the array elements are direct-initialized in increasing subscript order.)

Т.е. код в этой части вполне валиден и собирается в *clang* и *gcc*.